# Cube process incremental 1 partition vs multiple

Tags: sql-server, ssas, partitioning, cube, data-partitioning

I have a large cube where processing times have become too long. I want to change my cube partitioning and processing options. I understand that process incremental will pull new records into the cube. My question is, is there an advantage of having multiple partitions and performing process incremental rather than just having one partition and performing process incremental? I do not expect a large volume of new records each time I process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of having multiple partitions is that you can load into each in parallel. If the volume of new records isn't very large, and the processing time quick you could get away with just one partition.

The problem with having multiple partitions is that you will have to manage what data is exposed to each partition. If the same data is processed into multiple partitions, then you'll get duplicates in the cube.